# Get value between matching tags? (CodeMirror)

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I'm using Codemirror 5.3.

I'm tag matching html in a mixed-mode document to highlight the start and end tags - this works well. (https://codemirror.net/demo/matchtags.html)

I'm trying to capture the content between markers (in my case using a context-menu action where I right-click on tags), so I can send it off to an external process.

I use `var tm = doc.getAllMarks();` and because I'm tag matching and not bookmarking, I pretty much know there's only going to be two items in the array. However, the TextMarker array that this returns doesn't (as far as I can tell) contain the `{line, ch}` cursors for the marks.

Is there a proper way to get the starting and ending positions of the marks - either directly or as lines and character positions? The best I can think of is iterating each:

```
[].lines[0].parent.lines
```

and looking to see if each instance of CodeMirror.Line has a `markedSpans` object, which would the give me the line index, and then use `[].lines[0].markedSpans[0].from` and `[].lines[0].markedSpans[0].to` to find the positions of the characters in the mark. And then use `doc.getRange` to grab the content and shuffle it off for processing... something like this:

```
var tm = doc.getAllMarks(),
    lines = tm[0].lines[0].parent.lines,
    range = {
        from: { line: 0, ch: 0},
        to: { line: 0, ch: 0 }
    },
    hack = 0,
    textContent = "";
for (var i=0,j=lines.length;i<j;i++) {
    if (lines[i].hasOwnProperty("markedSpans")) {
        if (hack==0) { // sorry, i'm in a hurry
            range.from.line = i;
            range.from.ch = lines[i].markedSpans.from;
            hack=1;
        } else {
            range.to.line = i;
            range.to.ch = lines[i].markedSpans.to;
        }
    }
}
textContent = doc.getRange(range.from,range.to);
```

All this sounds pretty glitchy, and I'm looking for a better way.

Comment: `editor.getLineNumber(editor.getAllMarks()[1].lines[0])`

Comment: `editor.getAllMarks()[1].lines[0].markedSpans[0]` .from and .to is == .ch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `.find()` on an object returned by [`markText`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#markText), it will return the `{from, to}` position of the marker (or `null` if the marker was cleared).

Comment: OOH, ok. And now you've mentioned it, I've found where it says this in the documentation. And look at the mess I was getting myself into above! *shame*. Here's my whole solution now: `var tm = doc.getAllMarks(),
textContent = doc.getRange(tm[0].find().from,tm[1].find().to);`